# An example of a http proxy parsing the "Connection" header?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-proxy

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> HTTP/1.1 proxies MUST parse the Connection header field before a message is forwarded and, for each connection-token in this field, remove any header field(s) from the message with the same name as the connection-token.

Could somebody please give an example of a common scenario the above paragraph is referring to?

Does that have anything to do with `Connection: close` header?

Answer (score 3):

A good example, in HTTP/1.1, is [`Upgrade`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.7), to indicate that a client wishes to move from HTTP/1.1 to another protocol:

```
 GET http://www.example.com/hello.txt HTTP/1.1
 Connection: upgrade
 Upgrade: HTTP/2.0, SHTTP/1.3, IRC/6.9, RTA/x11
```

If this were a proxy, the `Upgrade` header should not be passed to any upstream servers, as it only makes sense for this connection.

The `Keep-Alive` header could also appear here in HTTP/1.0 but is now obsolete with HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Thanks
Got a link for reference @
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-proxy-connection-header.html

Comment: @joe So am I correct in my understanding that, if you have a basic reverse proxy http server (that is not altering any content that it passes to the application server), the proxy server should just eliminate the any ```Connection``` headers from the request header before it passes the request to the application server?

Comment: @Malvin9000 Yes, see [What Proxies Must Do](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/07/11/what_proxies_must_do#1-remove-hop-by-hop-headers) - "The number one thing that proxies must do is remove hop-by-hop headers before forwarding messages".

Comment: @Joe Thanks man, literally just found that blog post about 30 minutes ago, glad I'm on the right track. Thank you!